# ViewState in my Wizard

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have a Wizard to Add an Employee from my org. In Step1, I have few controls, one of them is EmpID (PK). The problem arrives in Step2, where I have only one control that is DropDownList1 which is binded from Datasource (code-behind). I want this value of DropDownList1 and EmpID from previous Step to insert it into another table called 'dbo.Emp_Skills'.

'dbo.Emp_skills' table has 2 columns:

EmpID (FK) | SkillID (FK)

How do I insert value of EmpID into this table when it is not actually saved? 
I can simply insert value of my DropDownList like this after my connections..

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SkillID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

But how do I insert the EmpID into the table?
EmpID and CertID are both FK in the dbo.Emp_Cert.. Will it be a problem??

I have used ViewState in Page_Load like this-

Well I have used simple ViewState something like this-

```
 if(ViewState["NameOfUser"] != null)
            NameLabel.Text = ViewState["NameOfUser"].ToString();
        else
            NameLabel.Text = "Not set yet...";
```

---

I used Label1 Control in Step2 of Wizard.

```
protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["NameOfUser"] =  TextBox1.Text;
            NameLabel.Text = TextBox1.Text;

        }
```

And then I used to insert that-

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SkillID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

But it is not working..

Comment: where is EmpID value in step1 ? IN which control it is present ?

Comment: Hello.. It is present in TextBox1..

Comment: use this `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SkillID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID",  ViewState["NameOfUser"].ToString());`

Comment: Thanks.. But when I click 'Next' in Step1, the NameLabel is not getting updated. It still says 'Not set yet...'.

Comment: in which page event you had placed this code ` if(ViewState["NameOfUser"] != null)
            NameLabel.Text = ViewState["NameOfUser"].ToString();
        else
            NameLabel.Text = "Not set yet...";` ??????

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have used that in Page_Load.. And other codes in separate class in code behind of the Wizard page..

Comment: what error you are getting now ?

Comment: I am not getting any response..

Comment: what do you want ? You can get the value from viewstate as i mentioned. label1.Text = ViewState["NameOfUser"].ToString();

Comment: Okay.. All I want is I need to insert value of EmpID into table called dbo.Contacts (Address1, Add2, CityID, EmpID).
Please take a look at this http://forums.asp.net/t/1828648.aspx/1?Save+values+between+Steps+in+Wizard+

Comment: ok first check are u getting the data from DropDownList1 and viewstate ? what is your problem i saw your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using asp.net wizard control, your TextBox1 is still there on  the page, and you can access its value.

This would work.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SkillID", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Yes, I use asp.net wizard control and I tried that ways, but it was not working..

Comment: It is not giving any errors. Just that it doesn't store values into the table .

Comment: Debug and check the value for `TextBox1.Text`. If you have `ViewState` enabled, its value should persist event after you move ahead in the wizard