# Insert modified date in the table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table for `Contacts` that I'm storing for customers with columns:

- Addressline1
- Addressline2
- CityID
- EmpID (FK)
- ModifiedDate (Computed, DateTime)

I use ASP.NET 4.0 and in the form I have used ASP.NET wizard with 3 steps. I have few problems.

1. How do I insert `EmpID` into a table `dbo.Contacts` where `EmpID` is a FK.
2. How to store `ModifiedDate` ? What is the sqlparameter to add the Time value?

Comment: How is ModifiedDate "computed"?

Comment: DB designer assigned it as Computed..

Comment: It is not computed from anything else.. Just mentioned it as Computed.

Comment: What is your data aceess technology? What "database designer" you use? What is your problem with assigning `EmpId`? Do you have a sample of code demonstrating what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I use SQL Server 08 and NET 4.0.
This is where I explained my concern with FK.. 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693777/viewstate-in-my-wizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically two choices to keep a `ModifiedDate` up to date:

1. define a `DEFAULT` constraint on that column to get the current date/time when you freshly insert a row, and create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to update the `ModifiedDate` after every update operation on that row
2. set the `ModifiedDate` in your client application before every save operation to the database

**Update:** if you want to create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, use code something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateModifiedDate
ON dbo.YourTableHere
AFTER UPDATE
AS
     UPDATE dbo.YourTableHere
     SET ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
     WHERE AddressID IN (SELECT AddressID FROM Inserted)
```

Here, I'm assuming your table `YourTableHere` has some kind of a primary key - a column like an `ID` that uniquely and clearly identifies each single row. Based on that row, you can update the `ModifiedDate` of all those rows that have been updated by a given SQL statement. `Inserted` is a pseudo table that's available inside a trigger code body, which contains all the rows that have been modified by the operation that caused this trigger to fire (all rows affected by your `UPDATE` statement on `YourTableHere`)

Read more about triggers here:

- [An Introduction to Triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i)
- [MSDN documentation on CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- [SQL Trigger Example in SQL Server 2008](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

**Update #2:** if your `ModifiedDate` column is in fact **computed** on the SQL Server table level, you **cannot** update it directly. You'll need to find out what it's computed from, and then you need to modify that column (if you can).

To find out what it's computed from, run this query on your SQL Server database:

```
SELECT 
    c.name, c.is_computed, c.definition
FROM 
    sys.computed_columns c
WHERE 
    object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Contacts')
    AND c.Name = 'ModifiedDate'
```

Comment: How do I use AFTER UPDATE trigger in my app for ModifiedDate? Any links to show me how to do it? Thanks,

Comment: Thanks a lot.. One doubt one 'Inserted' keyword here. I do have a PK called AddressID (PK- AutoIncrement).. So 'Inserted' is the table where I inserted?

Comment: @Girish: `Inserted` is a **pseudo table** that only exists during the lifetime of the trigger. If your `UPDATE` statement touched 10 addresses, then `Inserted` will contain the new values for those 10 rows that have been updated. It will have the same columns as your table that the trigger is connected to, e.g. in your case, if your table has `AddressID`, there will be a column in `Inserted` that contains the newly inserted auto-increment ID's

Comment: The trigger cannot be created since the ModifiedDate is "computed".. How do I proceed?

Comment: Sure, but the error I got when creating Trigger is this: `The column "ModifiedDate" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.`

Comment: What is computed btw.. Because when the table was created it was declared as `[Modifieddate]  AS (getdate())` getdate() means Computed?

Comment: @Girish: yes, that means, your column `ModifiedDate` will **always be showing the current date/time** whenever you inspect its value.... not exactly what you want! Drop that column and re-create it **without** the ` AS GETDATE()` part

Comment: Hello I just added value like this `Insert into dbo.Contact (Addressline1, Addressline2, CityID, EmpID)
Values ('adasd', 'adf3', 2, '1111');` and it worked. Datetime is automatically getting updated.

Answer (score -1):

YOU can use simple UPDATE statement when you are modifying date
like..

```
 update tabelname set modifieddate='@Prameterdate' where empid='01'
```